# How to access value in a nested array or subarray using a Ruby method?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, nested, sub-array

This is the array:

```
array = [ 1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6] ]
```

Can I use "delete_at" method to delete the "5"?

```
array.delete_at[x] method
```

What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: `array[3].delete_at(1)`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete the element `array[3][1]` (whatever its value) or do you want to delete the `5`, not knowing where it is in the array (and assuming the array has a particular structure)?

Comment: Please show what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 3):

Your 'array' has only 4 elements. If it's subarray you probably should do something like that

```
array[3].delete_at(1)
```

to delete the second element of subarray that's a fourth element of 'array' array.

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

This one is longer and less efficient but it allows you to select the item to be deleted by value instead of by position (array index). That's useful when you don't know the position.

```
array.map {|x| x.delete(5) if x.instance_of?(Array); x}
```